# S3 method for class not imported in package

Tags: r, r-s3

We have multiple methods for different classes in our R package, but all of them are so far from packages we import in the Description.

Now, we want to write more methods for classes that are so far no dependency of our package. This works fine, if the necessary package is in the namespace and hence, the class is known to R. Then, we don't need to import the package in ours.

However, it feels a bit wrong to do that. Is there a best practice for such cases? 
Pro of not importing it would be fewer dependencies, con the user would have to actively load the package with the class he wants to use our functions.

**Update**

@Roland `Enhances` in fact reads like the thing we are after - though I have never seen it in any package so far. However, we are not really accessing objects ... there is a modified `as` to coerce in the package, but that is exported via methods, so we need to import methods.

The only thing we are doing is:

```
foo.objectfromotherclassnotinimports <- function(x){
x  <- methods::as(x, "class_from_package_we_already_imported")
x2 <- foo2(x)
return(x)
}
```

Comment: It appears your package "enhances" other packages by providing methods for their classes? That case is explicitly covered by Writing R Extensions: "Finally, the ‘Enhances’ field lists packages “enhanced” by the package at hand, e.g., by providing methods for classes from these packages" and "As noted above, packages in ‘Enhances’ must be used conditionally and hence objects within them should always be accessed via `::`. "

Comment: Another source to look into: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html I think you are looking for `Suggests` and the  `if (!requireNamespace("pkg", quietly = TRUE))` condition.

Comment: I'd look at the `Reverse enhances` of the [Matrix package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/index.html) or the [lme4 package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) for some examples to follow.